# Werkzeug password encryption

Tags: security, encryption, hash, werkzeug, websecurity

I am trying to encrypt a password using werkzeug library. I don't know what why i am getting *pbkdf2:sha256:600000* for every any password i try to encrypt.

Here's my code

```
import werkzeug
# from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac

x = werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash(password="123456", method="pbkdf2:sha256", salt_length=8)
print(x)
```

Here's the output i am getting
**pbkdf2:sha256:600000$hbZ2Diwi$228e3cae24487c6a59de2947dda1e86312a4cfe451d024c53d56514ea41d7953**
I just want to return the string after **pbkdf2:sha256:600000** but i don't want to slice the string.

Comment: Please use the official / reference documentation before asking here on [so], we don't like wasting time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that took at least seconds to look up.

You can use [this separate function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac) that your function according [to the official documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/utils/#module-werkzeug.security):

> ... pbkdf2, the default. The parameters are hash_method and iterations, the default is `pbkdf2:sha256:600000`. See `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac()`.

Even the link is provided. You can return the base 64 instead of the hex by calling `b64encode(dk).decode()` instead of `dk.hex()`. It should return the same value (given the identical iteration count & salt value, of course).

Comment: I tried *hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac()* but i don't know what value to pass for salt argument.

Comment: The salt value should be unique for each hash. You can use any cryptographic random byte array, say 16 bytes. You'd need to keep this value with the hash, or have a value that is kept otherwise but is unique. Without a salt the resulting hash (or partial encryption) is vulnerable against pre-computation attacks, rainbow tables and such.